# Ember.js: Action bubbles up to wrong route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a main page, and for this example I'll call it `Book`.  There is a `BookController`, `Book` (model), `BookRoute`, and `book` (template).

Within the `book` template, there is a search form, that allows people using the application to search for authors in the database (authors that may have nothing to do with the current `book`.  I'd like this search form to be managed by it's own model/view/controller/route so it could be easily droppable in other parts of the application.  **So I use `{{render "search"}}` in the `book` template.**

I then made the `SearchController`, `SearchResult`, `SearchRoute`, and `search` template:

```
<!-- template -->
{{input type="text" value=query}}
<button type="button" {{action "search"}}>Search</button>

// main controller
App.SearchController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'search-result',
  query: '',

  actions: {
    search: function () {
      console.log('in controller');
      return true;  // returning true to have it bubble to the route
    }
  }
});

// item controller to decorate each search result
App.SearchResultController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});

// route for the search controller
App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    search: function () {
      console.log('in route');
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see, I'd like the user to hit the Search button, the action to go to the SearchController, then bubble up to the SearchRoute.  According to this chart, that is how this is supposed to work: http://emberjs.com/images/template-guide/action-bubbling.png

Looking at the chart above, I would think the action would take this path:

> Search button -> SearchController -> SearchRoute

However, this is what is happening:

> Search button -> SearchController -> **BookRoute**

Instead of going to the `SearchRoute`, the action is being bubbled up to the `BookRoute`, which is not where I want to put the functionality.  Is there any way I can get the action to go to the `SearchRoute` instead?  Or am I designing thing completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Routes are for things that are routable, the things that you can reach with an URL. Like the `BookRoute`.

If you are, however, simply rendering a controller inside a template with `{{render}}` no route is going to be created (obviously).

Why would you want it to bubble to its own route, anyway? Simply handle it inside the `SearchController`.

(Depending on what it actually does, you might as well try to handle it inside `ApplicationRoute`.)

Comment: I need it to go to a route because I also need it to access the store, which is only accessible from the route.  If I have to just shove everything like this into the ApplicationRoute, then that's just messy code.  Is there any way I can get it to go to the correct route?

Comment: You can't have an action bubble to a route that is not active. And why is the store only accessible from the route? Ember-data, for one, exposes `store` to both routes and controllers.